# Need help writing an update query to avoid using a loop

Tags: sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014. I have two tables. One for order numbers (Orders) and one for staging locations for the orders (StagingLocations).

Orders

```
----------------------
| OrderNumber | Zone |
----------------------
| 1           | 1    |
| 2           | 1    |
| 3           | 1    |
| 4           | 1    |
| 5           | 1    |
| 6           | 1    |
| 7           | 1    |
----------------------
```

And

StagingLocations

```
---------------------------------
| Zone | Location | OrderNumber |
---------------------------------
| 1    | A        | NULL        |
| 1    | B        | NULL        |
| 1    | C        | NULL        |
| 1    | D        | NULL        |
| 1    | E        | NULL        |
| 2    | A        | NULL        |
| 2    | B        | NULL        |
| 2    | C        | NULL        |
| 2    | D        | NULL        |
| 2    | E        | NULL        |
---------------------------------
```

I need to update the StagingLocations table with the order numbers from the Orders table. Something basically like this:

```sql
UPDATE
   StagingLocations s
SET
   s.OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber
FROM
   StagingLocation s INNER JOIN
   Orders o ON s.Zone = o.Zone
WHERE
   o.OrderNumber IS NULL
```

To achieve this:

```
---------------------------------
| Zone | Location | OrderNumber |
---------------------------------
| 1    | A        | 1           |
| 1    | B        | 2           |
| 1    | C        | 3           |
| 1    | D        | 4           |
| 1    | E        | 5           |
| 2    | A        | NULL        |
| 2    | B        | NULL        |
| 2    | C        | NULL        |
| 2    | D        | NULL        |
| 2    | E        | NULL        |
---------------------------------
```

But what I'm ending up with when using that query is one order number in all the locations with the matching zone instead of every order number in its own location.

I know I could achieve the results I want with a loop. But I've read that I should try to avoid loops in SQL. So I'd really like to be able to do this with a query. I just can't seem to come up with a way to do it on my own.

Any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not clear what you want.  So what's wrong with your query the the output?  The output matches your query.  Post your expected output.

Comment: The output I posted does not match the query I posted. The output is the result I want. The query is my failed attempt at getting those results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need another column to match the tables Orders and StagingLocations. We'll use `ROW_NUMBER` in this case.

```
update sl 
set OrderNumber=oc.OrderNumber
from StagingLocations sl
join (
    select Zone,Location, row_number() over (partition by Zone order by Zone, location) i
    from StagingLocations
) slc on sl.Zone=slc.Zone and sl.Location=slc.Location
join (
    select OrderNumber, Zone, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Zone order by Zone, OrderNumber) i
    from orders
) oc on slc.Zone=oc.Zone and slc.i=oc.i
where sl.OrderNumber is null
```